# Change guest username

Tags: unity, users, rename, guest-session

Now, looking around on Google shows me some ways in which to customise the settings of the Guest session. But, I would love a way to change the name of the Guest account.

Basically, I'm planning to take some laptops out to a school in Africa and want to rename the "Guest" account in 14.04 to "Student" so the students use that. They tend to store stuff on USB sticks and **they're using the Guest account so they can't break anything.**
*EDIT: I'll expand on this slightly. They're using the guest account simply for the reason it doesn't save anything after logoff. This was a specific thing the teachers have asked for.*

I don't mind if the actual username remains guest behind the scenes, but as long as it shows up as Student to on Unity. Any way of going about this?

Comment: I think it would require patching and rebuildning of a few packages, so practically I'd say no. As regards customization in general, I hope that Google took you to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Comment: Yeah, it did. Shame to know it can't be done, it would have been great to just change what it showed on the logon screen, but that page only tells me how to change settings once I'm in.

Comment: Actually I think it's a good thought. Why not file a wishlist bug against unity-greeter about making the guest session label customizable?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a user named "Student" as `standard` account, without admin permission.

Go to System Settings->User Acoounts, then unlock and create a new user:

[image: New user]

Comment: Because I need the account to not save anything at the end - that's the reason for the guest session. Using a standard account is not what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

**Change A User's Login**

This will change only the user's login name.

```
# usermod -l newname oldname
```

**Change the Real Name**

This will change the real name of the username.

```
# usermod -c "New Real Name" username
```

Comment: A guest accout is created when you start a guest session and after the session is finished, the new created guest account is removed (deleted)... So your answer is useless.